# Spacetime and quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity

In special relativity, the particle has a fixed world line in spacetime. So its whole trajectory is determined. But how can we represent the world line of the particle in spacetime when we take quantum mechanics into account? Because if we represent it by a line, then its motion would be deterministic.

Comment: Well, an "extended body in quantum mechanics" should be a system with more than one quantum particle that is not well-described by classical mechanics, right? So I think there are lots of examples of this - Condensates, Superfluids, maybe even simple conductors. And I think we can easily say "trajectories in quantum mechanics are paths and come with a phase" a la Path Integrals. I think the question makes sense, is what I'm getting at, and there are some reasonable answers.

Comment: @levitopher: The paths in the path integral don't have physical significance. You can look at path integrals as the Santa Clause interpretation of quantum mechanics: the system has to take _all_ possible paths and that's an infinite number potentiated to infinity. No classical system can possibly do this. When we realistically describe extended objects in classical mechanics, we are not doing it with a simple trajectory, either, but with statistical mechanics. All of the examples you mention are far more complex than a simple classical trajectory, in CM and in QM.

Comment: "The paths in the path integral don't have physical significance" is akin to a specific interpretation of quantum mechanics, i.e. some single-world approach. All of these are tip of the iceberg things, I understand, but saying there are NO trajectories in quantum mechanics, and *that's* the problem with this question I think is dismissive. There is a sense in which a quantum particle can have a (set of possible) trajectories, and we have a well-defined procedure to sort out the probability for each one.

Comment: @levitopher: Physics has an ontology based on measurable quantities. Trajectories and the paths in the path integral are not measurable. Unless you believe in the equivalent of angels dancing on the tip of needles, the entire idea is unscientific.

Answer (score 8):

This is precisely what Richard Feynman achieved. This is known as the [path integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation) approach to quantum mechanics. In classical mechanics, the world line is considered to be the solution to the Euler-Lagrange equations. So if you had an action, all you have to do is find the solution to the Euler-Lagrange EOMs and there you go - you get a parametrized world line.

However, in quantum mechanics, the particle's evolution from point $A$ to point $B$ is given by the weighted average over all the possible paths from $A$ to $B$. The "weighted average" is in fact derived from a probabilistic measure and therefore, the notion of the world line in quantum mechanics is still probabilistic. So the line that you are referring to in the last line of your question is basically the classical limit which is the probabilistic average of an infinite number of world lines.

As Sanya points out in his/her answer, the notion of Schrödinger quantum mechanics is not compatible with SR because of ghost modes, i.e. propagating states of negative norm. This is fully and consistently merged with SR only using the Dirac formulation. So you need to be a bit careful as to how you introduce QM and SR - the Schrödinger equation does not treat space and time equally and you can see this in the fact that it is a second order derivative in space while it is a first order derivative in time.

Comment: But even if we talk about the weighted average, we still need to represent it in spacetime by a fixed line, hence the path of the particle in spacetime would still be deterministic :/

Comment: Just because you draw one line to represent the motion of the particle, doesn't mean it is deterministic. The representation that you are referring to is exactly what it is : A pictorial representation. You cannot determine the actual particle worldline by just drawing lines. You have to take into account quantum interactions and other things. The logic you seem to advocate is similar to  saying "The pictorial representation this triangle is a right angle triangle, but when I find out the angles, it is obtuse. Therefore the calculation is wrong."

Answer (score 3):

Schrödinger Quantum Mechanics is built in a world with an absolute time and absolute space - thus combining special relativity and simple quantum mechanics is not a good idea. From a Kuhnian perspective I would even go as far as to call the theories incompatible. First approaches to generalise quantum mechanics towards a relativistic theory led to the Dirac theory and - because there were particles with negative energies (or something like that) which seemed strange - in the end towards todays quantum field theories, which present a fully relativistic theory of quantum effects.

Answer (score 1):

You are partially right. In Special Relativity, the trajectory of a mass is a "worldline" in four dimensional Minkowski-spacetime.

But in Quantum Mechanics, the development of quantum systems are not described as trajectories in Spacetime, rather they are described by the Schrödinger-equation, which is a three-dimensional partial differential equation.

There have been unifications of these two concepts by the Klein-Gordon-equation or the Dirac-equation, which are the foundation of relativistic Quantum Mechanics.